# How to stop bind to do a separate CNAME query again?

Tags: bind, dnsmasq, named-conf

I have a local DNS server like the following:

```
client -> bind (only handle local names) -> dnsmasq (handle other names)
```

This problem is when a name is a CNAME, dnsmasq return both CNAME and IPs, this is a expected result. But when bind saw a CNAME, it will always start a separate CNAME query, and the query goes to an unexpected DNS server.

For example:

`static.test.com` is configured with server `8.8.8.8` in dnsmasq, and it's CNAME is `xxx1234343.cloudfalre.com`.

The expected result is server `8.8.8.8` does all the DNS work, and client should receive the response from `8.8.8.8`.

But in this scenario, bind will do a CNAME query again, and this time query name is `xxx1234343.cloudflare.com`, and the query will go to another DNS server other than `8.8.8.8`.

How to I configure bind to use the query result, and stop resolve CNAME again?

Comment: I have tried forward only, but It does not work

Comment: What is your actual bind configuration as settings like [`minimal-responses`](https://bind9.readthedocs.io/en/v9.18.13/reference.html#namedconf-statement-minimal-responses)  , [`recursion`](https://bind9.readthedocs.io/en/v9.18.13/reference.html#namedconf-statement-recursion) and others will influence what Bind will do and show you.

Comment: minimal-responses yes;
recursion yes;